# Visit UK 2 Years Visa - Investment Complication

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian, I intend to apply for 2 years visa.

My concerns are these.

1. I don't leave cash in my salary account but I have maintained a minimum balance of 350k (750 Pounds)  and have been using my salary account for my investments. In July, when I got my first 6months Visa, I started running 2 mutual fund accounts (ARM and Stanbic) which I transfer 60k (128 Pounds) and 80k (170 Pounds) to the mutual accounts respectively, I do this same day I get my salary.
   The worth of both Mutual Funds is about 400k (854 Pounds) and 450k(960 Pounds) individually.
2. In August, I did a Treasury-Bills (Just like Fixed Deposit) investment of 1,000,000 (2,135 Pounds) for 91 days tenor which dropped in my account in November and in the same month of November I did another one for 91 days and it dropped on Jan 31, 2019.

Since I will be applying for 2 years visa this month, I decided to let the money rest in my account. The balance of my salary account is about 1,400,000 (3,100 Pounds)

Questions?
1. Do I need to get a letter for both mutual funds accounts and statements?

2. Do I have to provide the Treasury-bills certificate for the already matured investments so that it won't be termed as Lodgement?
3. Hope its qualifies / eligible for 2 years visa, and not make my application complicated.

Basic info.
- My salary is 260,000 Naira (555 Pounds)
- Im single
- Family invitation (Uncle)
- Travel History: Israel, UAE, UK, Ireland

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What is your premise for applying for a long-term Standard Visitor visa? How will you demonstrate that you need to visit the UK regularly?

Comment: @Traveller thats why am here. How do i demonstrate that??

Comment: We have no idea, based on what you've written.  The question you need to address is, as Traveller said, *how will you demonstrate that you need to visit the UK regularly?*  Your mutual funds have nothing to do with that.

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong thing. Your finances seem to be in order and as long as you provide documentation of your finances, they should be fine. The question is, why do you want a long term visitor visa? These are given to frequent visitors to the UK who can demonstrate that they have a reason to visit frequently and already have a good history with visiting the UK. Your travel history seems to be OK, so what is your reason for wishing to visit frequently?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Basically, getting a 2 years uk visa will relief me of queuing at the visa office for 2years plus I will like to visit my uncle and his family frequently.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen lol you. Can I walk you through my online application form?

Comment: The last 6 months visa i had was used just once. This is my first 2 years application.

Comment: Thank you so much @HonoraryWorldCitizen

**Under the income and savings session**

I checked Investment - Since I am running Mutual Funds Investment
and Another income - I have established that i run some services as a part-time hobby where i get between 20k - 80k paid in cash or transfer to my account.

In the **The total amount of money that you get in a year** session
i put 4,200,000 which is my annual salary excluding tax (3,120,000) plus my other income 960,000 ( 80,000 x 12 if all things being equal) and investment say i get 50k interest. Making a total of 4.1 Million.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen    
While in the **How much money do you have in savings (in GBP)*** ? session
I put 4,914 GBP
I calculated my investments and my closing account balance then converted it to GBP
which is 100,000 plus 1,700,000 respectively equals 2,700,000 ( 5,769 GBP)

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I can't thank you enough. In the session that says:
**Give details of the main purpose of your visit and anything else you plan to do on your trip. See tourist and short stays for more information**  Please see my respons **MY LAST VACATION TO THE UK WAS VERY INTERESTING AND EXCITING, I REALLY ENJOYED MY STAYED, I WILL LIKE TO VISIT MORE FREQUENTLY AND SEE MORE EXCITING PLACES LIKE QUEENS GALLERY, TOWER OF LONDON,LONDON ZOO, TRAFALGAR SQUARE, SEA LIFE LONDON, AND AQUARIUM**

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen **I WILL ALSO BE HAVING FUN, CRUISING, SIGHTSEEING, ACTIVITIES, VACATIONING, RECREATIONAL ACTIVITIES, RELAXING, AND SHOPPING. IF I AM GIVEN ANOTHER OPPORTUNITY**                        **************** I hope this is fine?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen **Let me rephrase then** My last family visit vacation was very interesting and exciting, I really enjoyed my stay, I will like to visit my family more frequently. Additionally, I will also like to see exciting places like Queens Gallery, London Zoo, Trafalgar square, Sea life London, and aquarium among others. Also for shopping, relaxing and just having fun. If I am given the opportunity. Hope this is perfect

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen Have i done anything wrong?

Comment: Hello. @olowogbo did you end up getting it bro?